# prevent dash from searching files

Tags: 14.04, unity, unity-dash

How can I prevent ubuntu dash from searching my files?

I just want it to search my applications.

I used `unity tweak tool` which worked fine but after restarting ubuntu, again dash searches in my files

How can I fix this?

Comment: unfortunately there is no fix for that, yet :(

Comment: Removed my answer. The weird thing is: filter options do stick after a restart on my 14.04 system, not on my 14.10 (!) system.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Even weirder, I have 14.04 and filter not working on mine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setting the filter options manually and force it to stick after a restart

To set the "filter" option of Dash:

- Open Dash
- At the right, click on to "Filter results"
- Uncheck "Files & Folders" (Categories)

  [image]
- From now on, when you type a name, No Files or Folders will show up by default :

  [image]

#### How to force it to stick, even after a restart (workaround)

This setting *should* stick, also after a restart.

If it doesn't stick for some reason, you can force it, by adding a command (to run a tiny script) to your startup applications. The command in the script itself cannot be added *directly* to your startup applications because of the combination of single/double quotes that does not "fit" in a `.desktop` file.

*The script:*

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 15&&gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['files.scope']"
```

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `set_search.sh`
- Add the (command to run the) script to your Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

  ```
    sh /path/to/set_search.sh
  ```

*Note*

In the script, there is a "sleep" of 15 seconds built in, to give the desktop the time to load. It also means that it might take 10-15 seconds after login for the search filter to be set.

Comment: It did not stick after restart

Comment: @Yashar edited my answer, that should work!

Comment: @Yashar you're welcome, glad it worked out.